# Split up JSON Object into multiple <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, append, getjson

I'm currently trying to create a Character Ranking system similar to [this one.](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/2151576)

With the official API I am able to append all the data via `$.getJSON` and the URL into a table.

So far I'm showing 20 characters and got all the character data inside multiple table rows (one for each character), but haven't figured out how I can split up the character object into multiple `<td>`, so that I have better control of addressing them via CSS.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                $.getJSON("http://api.pathofexile.com/ladders/Standard?callback=?", function (result) {

                    $("#tdPlayer").append("<td>" + result["total"] + "</td>" + "<br/>");

                    $("#tdSince").append("<td>" + result["cached_since"] + "</td>" + "<br/>");

                    $.each(result["entries"], function (index, value) {
                        $("#tdRanking").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + JSON.stringify(index, null, '\t') + ": " + JSON.stringify(value, null, '\t') + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<br/>");

                    });
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <button>Anzeige der Top 20 Spieler in der Incursion Liga</button>

    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="tdPlayer">Anzahl der Spieler:</td>
                <td id="tdSince">Suchbeginn: </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" id="tdRanking">Spieler: (max. 20 angezeigt)</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: An example of how the currently appended character objects look like inside the table.]

The whole JSON object where I append my data from [can be found here](http://api.pathofexile.com/ladders/Standard).

Comment: we'd need to see the JSON

Comment: I've added a screenshot of how the table with the object currently looks like. And you can see the whole JSON object that I append via http://api.pathofexile.com/ladders/Standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the character properties within your $.each function using the non-stringified `value` variable. For example, to access the character name, use `value.character.name`

```
$("#tdRanking").append("<tr><td>" + JSON.stringify(index, null, '\t') + '<td>' + value.character.name + "</td></tr>");
```

I've added an example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBwpzj)

Please note that i am not using ajax to retrieve the data as your data source is not being served over https://

Comment: Is it possible to auto load the "var result" object each time instead to manually put the whole object there? So I could work with a filter option later on that can show more than just this specific case.

Comment: yes, the method you are using is fine for that. I used an object because your particular api didn't work over https

Comment: Ahh, I see! That works. Just got the problem that I want to have a <td> for each one inside the row so as an example

`$("#tdRanking").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + value.rank + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.character.name + "</td"> + "</tr>" + "<br/>");` 

I can see the result inside `console.log(value.rank + value.character.name)` but when trying to append it doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind - it works. I failed the " in the second closing of the "</td>"

Works like a charm now - thanks a lot!